# Increase ramdisk size on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, ramdisk

How can I increase the ramdisk size on a Ubuntu 9.10 system? I have read one technique is to change the ramdisk_size parameter in the /boot/grub/menu.lst file. However, I am unable to find this file on my system.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Ramdisk/ramdisk.html for how to do this.

If you can't find menu.lst, then your system might be using the new grub.cfg file.  Look in /boot/grub .

Answer (score 0):

This script create a ram disk, maximum ram usage is 256 Mbyte.

Note : available space is more, because the device use realtime compression.

You can run it with sudo or put the script in /etc/init.d/

```
#!/bin/bash

modprobe zram num_devices=1 
# max ram usage = 256 Mbytes
echo 262144 > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
mke2fs -q -m 0 -b 4096 -O sparse_super -L zram /dev/zram0
mount -o relatime,noexec,nosuid /dev/zram0 /mnt/zram
# eof
```